# Generic ObjectContext? objectContext.GetObjectSet<TEntity>?

Tags: entity-framework, generics, objectcontext, code-reuse, objectset

Is there a way to get `ObjectQuery<T>` for specfied generic type?

Pseudo:

```
public partial class MyObjectContext
{
    public ObjectSet<TEntity> GetObjectSet<TEntity>()
    {
        return Helper.GetObjectSet<TEntity>(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is what you need:

```
public partial class MyObjectContext
{
    public ObjectSet<TEntity> GetObjectSet<TEntity>()
    {
        return this.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
    }
}
```

As you can see your helper method is not needed because you can call `CreateObjectSet` directly on `MyObjectContext` instance. It will return `ObjectSet<TEntity>` which is derived from `ObjectQuery<TEntity>`. TEntity must be mapped type and it cannot be derived type in entity hierarchy.

Comment: thanks. I have 2 question: 1) Is it possible to create an object set of an inherited type (e.g. Company inherits from Contact, can I make an ObjectSet<Contact>?) 2) the problem is that the generated properties are lazy loaded, this function will constantly create a new ObjectSet, is there an efficient way to deal with it??

Comment: @Shimmy: Creating `ObjectSet` of inherited entity type will throw exception. I'm not sure how this participate in lazy loading? I think that creating ObjectSet doesn't have performance problems but I didn't test it.

Comment: do you think it would be efficient having a Dictionary<Type, ObjectSet> of the types that are already created and initializing them only once? or the dictionary and retrieval will cost even more?

Comment: @Shimmy: I don't know. You can test it. Write a simple test where you try to create ObjectSet million times and write a test where you try to retrieve ObjectSet from dictionary million times. Compare the timing.

Comment: As per the inheritance it's not a problem, I'll make the return type IQueryable<T> etc. and `var entityType = typeof(TEntity) while(!entityType.BaseType == typeof(EntityObject)) entityType = entityType.BaseType;` So I get the set of the superclass, then will return using `OfType<SubClass>()`.