# How to get the correct DB Entity at Runtime?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework

In my method:

```
public void DeleteSingleMrTypeByVersionIdAndId<T>(
    int version_id, int child_obj_id, CIHEntities _dbContext)
        where T : MrBase
```

I want to fetch the row from a DB entity. So, I have this:

```
IQueryable<T> old_items = _dbContext.???
            .Where(r => r.MrVersionEntityAssoc.Id == version_id)
            .Where(r => r.Id == child_obj_id)
            .Select(r => r);
```

But how do I write the LINQ statement so that it uses `T` to know where to get the row from?

Of course, just referring to it as `T` does not work.

```
IQueryable<T> old_items = _dbContext.T
            .Where(r => r.MrVersionEntityAssoc.Id == version_id)
            .Where(r => r.Id == child_obj_id)
            .Select(r => r);
```

We are using VS2012.

Thanks
Eric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you're looking for is `Set()`:

```
IQueryable<T> old_items = _dbContext.Set<T>()
    .Where(r => r.MrVersionEntityAssoc.Id == version_id)
    .Where(r => r.Id == child_obj_id)
    .Select(r => r);
```

---

**Edit:** The above applies when using `DbContext`. For `ObjectContext`, the corresponding method is `CreateObjectSet<T>()`.

```
IQueryable<T> old_items = _dbContext.CreateObjectSet<T>()
    .Where(r => r.MrVersionEntityAssoc.Id == version_id)
    .Where(r => r.Id == child_obj_id)
    .Select(r => r);
```

Comment: I looked in the class created by entity framework and there is not Set() method. Plus, it shows an error:`'MrdDataServices.Models.CIHEntities' does not contain a definition for 'Set' and no extension method 'Set' accepting a first argument of type 'MrdDataServices.Models.CIHEntities' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Uhmmm ... Is your `_dbContext` of type `DbContext`, as the name suggests?

Comment: No, it is of type `MrdDataServices.Models.CIHEntities`

Comment: I kinda figured that by the debugger output. What classes does `MrdDataServices.Models.CIHEntities` inherit from? What interfaces does it implement?

Comment: The code that is generated from the Entity Framework produced this: `public partial class CIHEntities : ObjectContext`. I already tried to use ObjectSet<T> but I get the same error as I reported when I tried Set<T>

Comment: As described here, `CreateObjectSet<T>()` is what you're looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5926616/961510

Comment: Yikes. That raises another issue with Database First Entity Framework. But that is another question.